# How to get text from html table?

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

I have a html:

```html
<table class= "tb1">
<thead>
<tr>
<th width="100">Country,<br>Other</br></th>
<th width="20">Total<br>Customers</br></th>
<th width="30">New<br>Customers</br></th>
<th width="30">Tests/<br/>
<nobr>1M cases</nobr>
</th>
<th style="display:none" width="30">Continent</th>
</tr>
</thead>
</table>
```

I use xpath to get texts from each row.

```
'//table[@class="tb1"]//thead//tr//th/text()'
```

The result is:

```
['Country,', 'Other', 'Total', 'Customers', 'New', 'Customers', 'Tests/', '\n    ', '\n    ', 'Continent']
```

Desired result:

```
['Country,Other', 'TotalCustomers', 'NewCustomers', 'Tests/1M cases', 'Continent']
```

I tried using:

```
'string(//table[@class="tb1"]//thead//tr//th)'
```

But the result is just:

```
Country,Other
```

Comment: Why not use a for-loop to combine the first 2 elements? Use a different Xpath selector to extract the 1M cases since it is not in the list.

Comment: first use `xpath` to select all `<th>` and later get text from every `<th>` using `for`-loop without using `xpath`

Comment: You could also use these XPath 2.0 expression: `replace(replace(normalize-space(string-join(//th,";"))," ;",";"),"/ ","/")` to return a string, `tokenize(replace(replace(normalize-space(string-join(//th,";"))," ;",";"),"/ ","/"),";")` to return a list of values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First use `xpath` to get every `<th>` and later use `for`-loop to get `'.//text()'` in every `<th>` and then you can clean (ie. remove "new line") and join elements to create one string for every `<th>`

```
import lxml.html

html ='''
<table class= "tb1">
<thead>
<tr>
<th width="100">Country,<br>Other</br></th>
<th width="20">Total<br>Customers</br></th>
<th width="30">New<br>Customers</br></th>
<th width="30">Tests/<br/>
<nobr>1M cases</nobr>
</th>
<th style="display:none" width="30">Continent</th>
</tr>
</thead>
</table>
'''

soup = lxml.html.fromstring(html)

results = []

for th in soup.xpath('//th'):
    text = ''.join(x.strip() for x in th.xpath('.//text()'))
    #text = ''.join(x.strip() for x in th.itertext())
    results.append(text)

print(results)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use BeautifulSoup4:

```
pip install beautifulsoup4
```

This will take your table and return a list for each row; header or data

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


html_text = '''<table class= "tb1">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th width="100">Country,<br>Other</br></th>
        <th width="20">Total<br>Customers</br></th>
        <th width="30">New<br>Customers</br></th>
        <th width="30">Tests/<br/>
            <nobr>1M cases</nobr>
        </th>
        <th style="display:none" width="30">Continent</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Country1</td>
        <td>20</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Europe</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Country2</td>
        <td>15</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>North America</td>
    </tr>
</tr>

</table>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, 'html.parser')

def get_table():
    table = []
    for tr in soup.find_all('tr'):
        # get headers
        th = tr.find_all('th')
        # get rows
        td = tr.find_all('td')
        # listify and combine them (just in case the html is structured weird somehow)
        row = [i.text for i in th] + [i.text for i in td]
        # append the new list to the table list
        table.append(row)
    return table

print(get_table())
```

Output:

```
[['Country,Other', 'TotalCustomers', 'NewCustomers', 'Tests/\n1M cases\n', 'Continent'], ['Country1', '20', '3', '1', 'Europe'], ['Country2', '15', '1', '3', 'North America']]
```

You could also make this a list of dictionaries with headers as keys and data as values which may be easier work with in python.

Comment: Thank you for your help!
Your solution's really exiting.

Comment: I really want to give you a mark. But cuz of @furas follow the tags so that I give him.  Thank you!

Comment: Glad I could help! If you want to know how to return a dictionary type from any html table, let me know. I might make a full package out of it (because I do it all the time) if there already isn't one on pypi.

Comment: It's great! Now I'm learning to crawl data from web. If you don't mind, I love to learn it.